# Pergunta sobre array em php

Tags: php, json, array

Estou quebrando a cabeça e já estou sem idéias, resumindo o meu código é assim:

```
<?php

$var = 'arquivo_1'; // podendo ser arquivo_1 ou arquivo_2

$arquivo_1 = array(
"algo1" => "alguem1",
"algo2" => "alguem2"
);

$arquivo_2 = array(
"algo1" => "alguem3",
"algo2" => "alguem4"
);

// a minha função é assim:

function array_file_writte($file_array,$array){ 
$content = serialize($array);
$fd = @fopen($file_array, 'w+');
fwrite($fd,$content);
fclose($fd);
chmod($file_array, 0644);
return true;
}

// se fosse assim fucionaria corretamente:

array_file_writte($file_array,$arquivo_1);

// mas o valor da variavel $var muda, então eu precisaria fazer assim:

$var_selecionada = '$'.$var;
array_file_writte($file_array,$var_selecionada);

//algum metodo???
// mas não dá certo por que o que ele grava no arquivo acaba não sendo a variavel serializada, alguma idéia????
```

Comment: Qual é a dúvida? não ficou clara, poderia [edit] a pergunta e adicionar os detalhes.

Comment: Acho que entendi, tente chamar a função assim `array_file_writte($file_array,$$var);`

Comment: nesse ponto `array_file_writte($file_array, $arquivo_1);` a variavel `$file_array` nao foi definida, entao o que ela deferia conter? O nome do arquivo?

Comment: A pergunta não está clara, por favor, edite ela e dê maiores detalhes.

Comment: Não está claro o suficiente, qual o problema proposto, recomento ver este [link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e editar a sua pergunta.

Comment: Se eu entendi direito vc quer $$var ao invés de '$'.$var.  E essa dúvida não tem a ver com arrays como o título e a hashtag deixaram a entender.

Answer (score 2):

E se voce simplesmente mudar a estrutura dos dados/array?

```
$arquivos = array(
    'arquivo_1' = array(
        "algo1" => "alguem1",
        "algo2" => "alguem2"
    ),
    'arquivo_2' = array(
        "algo1" => "alguem3",
        "algo2" => "alguem4"
    ),
);
```

Agora pega os valores assim

```
foreach($arquivos as $nome=>$valores){
    //... valores vai ser um array e $nome o indice atual, no caso arquivo_1 ou arquivo_2
    //processa a escrita dos arquivos aqui
    array_file_writte($nome, $valores);
}
```

E muda a funcao de escrita para algo como

```
function array_file_writte($nomeArquivo, $lista){ 
    $content = serialize($lista);
    $fd = @fopen($nomeArquivo, 'w+');
    fwrite($fd, $content);
    fclose($fd);
    chmod($file_array, 0644);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*Basta alterar o `$var_selecionada = '$'.$var;` para `$var_selecionada = $$var;`.*

---

Você deve usar `$$var` ao invés de `'$'.$var`, dessa forma irá criar uma variável variável, [veja isto aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.variable.php). Da maneira que está fazendo atualmente o `$` está sendo passado como string, o que não funciona.

Da forma mencionada ficaria:

```
$var = 'arquivo_1';

$arquivo_1 = array(
"algo1" => "alguem1",
"algo2" => "alguem2"
);

$arquivo_2 = array(
"algo1" => "alguem3",
"algo2" => "alguem4"
);

$var_selecionada = $$var;

var_dump($var_selecionada); // Somente para ver o resultado
```

Irá retornar:

```
array(2) { 
  ["algo1"]=> string(7) "alguem1" 
  ["algo2"]=> string(7) "alguem2" 
}
```

[Este isto aqui.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7f0d6621f05ff8e533a0b785a024ec54bf4ac0a9)

A variável variável, o `$$var`, irá executar o `$arquivo_1`, porque o `$var` foi definido por `$var = 'arquivo_1'`, no final irá fazer o que deseja.